# How can I draw a scalene triangle using LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

I wanted to draw the above triangle, but I was only able to draw the one below -

[image]

How do I draw the recreate the shape at the top? I am having trouble properly placing the x, y and producing the angle alpha and the right-angle sign.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (7,0);
    \coordinate (c) at (5,3);
    \draw (a) -- (b)node[midway, below]{$x$} -- (c)node[midway,right]{$z$} -- (a)node[midway,left, above]{c}; % Triangle.

    \draw (a) node[anchor=east,align=center] {A};
    \draw (b) node[anchor=west,align=center] {B};
    \draw (c) node[anchor=south]{C};

    %line
    \draw (2.366,2.451) -- (4.526,-0.789)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In addition, where can I learn the inside out of LaTeX and draw complex shapes like the one above?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: The shape you give is not an isoceles triangle.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!! The triangle doesn't look isosceles to me. That said, this kind of construction is easy with the `tkz-euclide` package: https://ctan.javinator9889.com/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/TKZdoc-euclide.pdf. And there is a lot of similar examples in this site. For example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214499/drawing-and-labeling-the-sides-and-angles-of-a-right-triangle

Comment: Really sorry for my carelessness.

Comment: On your side question “where can I learn the inside out…”, have you looked at the TikZ/PGF manual? (Linked [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) under “documentation”.) I had been using LaTeX for years before I realised that most packages have manuals, and many of them (including TikZ/pgf) are very well written, with helpful introductions, tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can place the points that define the line parallel to BC with the help of `calc` library. For example,

```
\coordinate (ab) at ($(a)!0.6!(b)$);
```

creates the point `(ab)` between `(a)` and `(b)` with distances of 60% from `(a)` and 40% from `(b)`.

Both angles can be drawn with the `angles` and `quotes` (the last for the labels) libraries. This

```
\draw[red] pic ["$\alpha$",draw] {angle=ac--ab--a};
```

draw an angle with vertex in `(ab)` and labels it as alpha.

The complete code could be:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   % coordinates
   \coordinate (a)  at (0,0);
   \coordinate (b)  at (7,0);
   \coordinate (c)  at ($(a)!0.5!(b)+(60:3.5)$);
   \coordinate (ab) at ($(a)!0.6!(b)$); % point for the line parallel to BC (calc library)
   \coordinate (ac) at ($(a)!0.6!(c)$); % point for the line parallel to BC (calc library)
   % triangle
   \draw (a) node [left] {$A$} -- (b) node [right] {$B$} -- (c) node [above] {$C$} -- cycle;
   % labels
   \node at ($(a)!0.5!(ab)$) [below] {$x$}; 
   \node at ($(ac)!0.5!(c)$) [above] {$y$};
   \node at ($(b)!0.5!(c)$)  [right] {$z$};
   % line
   \draw[shorten <= -1 cm, shorten >= -1cm] (ab) -- (ac);
   % angles (angles and quotes libraries)
   \draw[red] pic ["$\alpha$",draw] {angle=ac--ab--a}; 
   \draw[red] pic [draw,angle radius=3mm] {right angle=a--c--b}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** I changed C coordinates. Now it has a *right* angle.

Answer (score 4):

A possibility with `pstricks`, more precisely with `pst-eucl`, which  defines tools to mimick constructions with ruler & compass. In particular, I use here the `\pstHomO` command, which builds the homothetics of a family of points in a single step:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-0.5)(2,2)
\psset{PointSymbol=none, PointName=none, linejoin=1, linewidth=0.5pt}
\SpecialCoor
\pstTriangle[PosAngle={120,-130,-30}](2; 60){A}(-2,0){B}(2,0){C}
\pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize=0.2]{B}{A}{C} 
\pstHomO[HomCoef=0.6]{B}{A,C}[H,I]
\pstLineAB[nodesep=-0.5]{H}{I}
\pstMarkAngle[LabelSep=0.3, MarkAngleRadius=0.45]{H}{I}{B}{$\alpha$}
\foreach \s/\t/\lbl in {I/B/x, H/A/y, A/C/z} {\pstLabelAB[linestyle=none, offset=1ex]{\s}{\t}{$\lbl$}} 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]